# barplot with connected series

Tags: r, time-series, bar-chart

I have some data which are a set of percentages that change over time. I'd like to show this data as a stacked bar plot with lines connecting the series:

```
    m <-barplot(b)
    lines(c(m[1]+0.5,m[2]-0.5), c(0,0))
    lines(c(m[1]+0.5,m[2]-0.5), c( b[1,1], b[1,2]))
    lines(c(m[1]+0.5,m[2]-0.5), c( b[1,1]+b[2,1], b[1,2]+b[2,2]))
    lines(c(m[1]+0.5,m[2]-0.5), c( b[1,1]+b[2,1]+b[3,1], b[1,2]+b[2,2]+b[3,2]))
    lines(c(m[1]+0.5,m[2]-0.5), c( b[1,1]+b[2,1]+b[3,1]+b[4,1], b[1,2]+b[2,2]+b[3,2]+b[4,2]))
```

Doing the plot like this gets me this plot, but of course this scales badly when I want to a more columns or more parts per time point. I've tried doing the addition of the lines in a for loop, but I couldn't quite get it right. Does someone know how to do this in a more flexible way, or is there a package that implements this plot?

Comment: base graphics work like a pencil and paper in that you must plan your cat landscape ahead of time. Plan out how many cats you want to draw along a winding river landscape. If you only left space for 15 cats, you will have problems trying to fit in that 16th (and still very important) cat. `lattice` and `ggplot2` can do this on the fly, essentially, since lattice draws all 16 cats at once, and ggplot will adjust the length of the river so that you can insert as many cats as you like without starting from a new piece of paper. So I guess you want ggplot unless you want to redraw a lot of cats.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've looked at `lattice` and `ggplot2`, but would only let me separate series. I'm looking for a graph as described above. Also shown here: (https://www.dropbox.com/s/0unbnr99vmmd1ro/barplot_series.png)

Comment: ah I see. I don't even know what that is called

Comment: After spending some time figuring out the barplot function, I came up with a function that does the above, but more reproducible. See above.

Comment: nice work. post it as an answer and accept.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Disclaimer: this was extracted from the question.</sub>

Below is  an example of how to do this:

```
dat <- matrix(c(3,4,5,9,2,1,5,6,5,5,6,2), nrow=3)

color=c("darkgreen", "darkgrey", "gold", "darkblue")


barplot_series <- function(dat, color) {
    b <- barplot(dat, col=color, las=2)

    #columns i are the samples
    for (i in 1:dim(dat)[2] - 1 ) {
        if (i < 1) {next}
        print (c("column", i))

    #rows j: these are the individual clones
        for (j in 1: dim(dat)[1] ) { # or dim(dat)[1]-1
            if (j < 1) {next}
            print (c("row", j))
            if (j < 2) {
                lines(c(b[i]+0.5, b[i+1]-0.5), c(dat[j,i], dat[j,i+1]))
            }
            if (j > 1) {
                lines(c(b[i]+0.5, b[i+1]-0.5), c(colSums(dat[1:j,])[i], colSums(dat[1:j,])[i+1]))
            }
        }
    }
}

barplot_series(dat, color)
```

There are probably better ways of achieving the same, but this function generates the stacked bar plot with connected series that I was looking for and scales with the matrix containing the data.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above: here is the answer that I worked out for my initial question.

```
dat <- matrix(c(3,4,5,9,2,1,5,6,5,5,6,2), nrow=3)

color=c("darkgreen", "darkgrey", "gold", "darkblue")


barplot_series <- function(dat, color) {
    b <- barplot(dat, col=color, las=2)

    #columns i are the samples
    for (i in 1:dim(dat)[2] - 1 ) {
        if (i < 1) {next}
        print (c("column", i))

    #rows j: these are the individual clones
        for (j in 1: dim(dat)[1] ) { # or dim(dat)[1]-1
            if (j < 1) {next}
            print (c("row", j))
            if (j < 2) {
                lines(c(b[i]+0.5, b[i+1]-0.5), c(dat[j,i], dat[j,i+1]))
            }
            if (j > 1) {
                lines(c(b[i]+0.5, b[i+1]-0.5), c(colSums(dat[1:j,])[i], colSums(dat[1:j,])[i+1]))
            }
        } 
    }
}

barplot_series(dat, color)
```